# Microsoft CodePush App Center migration: future deployments

Tags: cordova, code-push, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using Microsoft's CodePush service for my Cordova app.  As noted [here](http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) this service will be migrated over the next 10-12 months to **App Center**.

It sounds like there will be a new CodePush SDK (aka cordova plugin) in February 2018.  If we do not use the new SDK when it comes out, but we start using the new **App Center** CLI to deploy releases, will the old CodePush SDK (cordova plugin) still work to pick up the newly deployed packages that were deployed from the **App Center** CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We highly recommend switching over to the new App Center CodePush SDK when it's completed. But, we understand there are circumstances that can prevent that from happening immediately.

We are committed to keeping the old SDK available until **late 2018**, which means you are free to use the old SDK with the App Center CLI until then.

Also, Cordova support in the App Center portal was recently released in preview. You can now view CodePush in the App Center portal as well as the App Center CLI.

Comment: Is there going to be a new Cordova Code Push plugin for the App Center migration?  The docs make it seem like the existing plugin (`cordova-plugin-code-push`) is still going to be used going forward, but the CLI is the main change point?